# How to introduce erc20 token to coinbase and give it its initial value

Tags: erc-20, coinbase, trading

How can I add my newly deployed token to coinbase to put it for trading, how can I associate to it a certain value in dollars? Is it something similar to the liquidity pools of the AMMs where you provide both the token amount and its counterpart and that would be the initial value of your token in that token?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the centralized exchange Coinbase, then you need to discuss with them about getting your token listed. It's most likely a very difficult and expensive process, and hard to get it listed.

The value for a token in a centralized exchange is initially decided by the exchange. After that it starts fluctuating based on supply and demand. But no, you don't provide a counterparty for it in a centralized exchange.

Comment: coinbase has their asset hub page, https://assethub.coinbase.com which seems to let you list an asset such as an ERC20 token. do you have any idea if this can be counted as a listing of the ERC20 token itself?

Comment: There's no way they would allow arbitrary tokens in their main exchange platform. Way too risky user experience. Looks like that site offers some random list where you can add your token and promote it.